# Discrepancy between size and number of iterations C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I create a pointer `p_dataStatStorage_` to an object of type:

```
STK::Array2D<std::vector<std::pair<int, float> > >
```

where `STK::Array2D` is a type of 2D container, with `elt()` as an accessor. At some point in my code I fill the vector of a particular cell `(ind, j)` with pushbacks of the form:

```
p_dataStatStorage_->elt(ind, j).push_back(std::pair<int, float>(currMod, currProba));
```

Later in the code, in another function, I need to read the couples that were pushed earlier. I then use the following code:

```
for (std::vector<std::pair<int, float> >::const_iterator itVec = p_dataStatStorage->elt(i, j).begin();
     itVec != p_dataStatStorage->elt(i, j).end();
     ++itVec)
{
  std::cout << "itVec->first: " << itVec->first << ", itVec->second: " << itVec->second << std::endl;
}
```

Problems are:

1. For every given couple `(i, j)`, the first `itVec->first` always output 0, no matter what was set earlier, while the rest (int or float) of the `std::pair<int, STK::Real>` are output correctly.
2. As I output the `size()` of each vector prior to the above loop, I always get the value number of elements corresponding to the data originally pushed. However, in some cases, the loop above has an infinite number of iterations, after the iterations described at 1., and the values output for the int are random, while the values output for the float are near zero.

Are there standard things I should check immediately ? I am a bit puzzled because if I check the elements pushed immediately, in the function where I pushed them, I get no errors, while if I do this in another function later I get the behaviour described above.

Comment: Are you multithreading by any chance? Are you sure the vectors are not being changed within the loop (by some code you did not include)?